# Should I repeat code in actual class in tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I want to test that a specific method produces the expected result, but to do that I need to manipulate the input in the test as well.

```
class ToTest {
  public String produceResponse(String input) {
    // ....
    encryptedIds = encryptIds(input)
    output = doStuff(input, encryptedIds)
  }

  public encryptIds(input) {
    ....
  }
}
```

In my test I need to check that produceResponse actually produces the expected response.
in order to do that I have to encrypt the ids in the input.

My question is: should I rewrite encryptIds in the test (so that I would have more controller on the result) or should I call encryptIds from the class itself.

Is there a better approach to solve this? I don't like that in my test I know what happens in the specific flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to test `produceResponse()` with known encryptedIds as input.

You could do that without refactoring the code, but it would probably be a good idea to refactor it, so that's what I'm going to explain:

```
class ToTest {

    private IdEncryptor encryptor;

    public ToTest(IdEncryptor encryptor) {
        this.encryptor = encryptor;
    }

    public String produceResponse(String input) {
        String[] encryptedIds = encryptor.encryptIds(input);
        return doStuff(input, encryptedIds);
    }
}
```

Now you can unit-test IdEncryptor to test that it produces correct encrypted IDs based on a String input.

And to test the ToTest class, you can mock the IdEncryptor so that whatever the input it receives, it produces the encryptedIds you desire. For example with mockito:

```
IdEncryptor mockEncryptor = mock(IdEncryptor.class);
when(mockEncryptor.encryptIds(any(String.class)).thenReturn(new String[] {"a", "b"});

ToTest toTest = new ToTest(mockEncryptor);
String response = toTest.produceResponse("input");
// expect that the response is what you expect given "a", "b" as input of doStuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Never copy any production code into the unit test as it will get outdated at some point.**
2. If both methods are public, they are part of the public API, so:

   - you should first unit test the correct behavior of the `encryptIds(String)` method
   - then unit test the `produceResponse(String)` method which will internally use the already tested `encryptIds(String)` method
3. If `encryptIds(String)` would not be part of the public API:

   - then it is internal implementation and helper method which is not unit testable
   - `produceResponse(String)` is then responsible for encryption as a side-effect:

     - you can still test it if you mark it package private (no modifier)
     - you can also change the implementation of the `encryptIds(String)` only for testing purposes

Comment: What if encryptIds is not part of the API?

Comment: Added more description

Answer (score 0):

Is encrypting id's something that is integral to your system or not? As it stands this class takes some input and produces some output and as far as your test is concerned this is what's important, no more, no less.

What is the impact of not performing the encryption? If your `doStuff` method will just fail if it doesn't happen then it is an internal detail to your class-under-test and I wouldn't have the tests care about it at all.  If it's a step that absolutely must be performed then I would refactor the code to verify that it absolutely has happened, maybe using a mock as @jb-nizet answered.

As for the general case of duplicating production code in tests, as @Crazyjavahacking stated you should not do this, but I have no issue with *using* production code from a test- maybe not at a unit level but definitely the higher up the system I go, e.g. when testing writing to a DB I will use the reading code to verify it's happened correctly, but will also have independent tests to verify the reading path as well